# Keep a button active even after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to keep the selected button active after the button is clicked, which changes the page. My current setup is

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default nav" id="btn" type="button" href="index.php?mode=option">Option</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    //Variable of previously selected
    var selected = [];

    //Setup Buttons
    $('.nav').button().click(function() { 
        //Enable previous
        if(selected[0]) {
            selected.button('enable').removeClass('active'); 
        }    

        //Cache the previous
        selected = $(this);

        //Disable this and keep color attributes
        selected.button('disable').addClass('active');

        //Do Normal Button Click Stuff Here
        $('#data').text(selected.text() + ' was clicked');
    });
    $('#btn').click();
});
```

Currently all this does is the button `Option` is active, I click another, it changes to active but then it goes back to `Option` being active.

I'd also like to be able to use this JS without having to have `nav` in the class of the button.

Comment: What exactly are you after. When the link is clicked it will go to index.php which would mean it would be set onload so any javascript that runs on lick will have little effect

Comment: I'm actually using a php include script to include/change the page when the button is clicked, so it is changing page. @WayneEllery

Comment: So when the page changes, you would need to use php to change the styles of the button that was clicked. To know what was clicked you would pass the id in the query string

Comment: The buttons are in the index not the php file that I include. @WayneEllery